# How to override the Get method in Web API in C#.net

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services

I have created web api using Entity Frame work in C#.net. I have a controller class in which i have defined some methods like this.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Net.Http;
 using System.Web.Http;
 using Test_Net_Test_Info.Models;

 namespace Test_Net_Test_Info.Controllers
 {
 public class InfosController : ApiController
 {
    public List<Info> Get()
    {
        return InfoRepository.GetAllInfos();
    }
    public Info Get(int id)
    {
        return InfoyRepository.GetInfoById(id);
    }
    public Info Get(string company)
    {
        return InfoRepository.GetInfoByCompany(company);
    }
    public Info Get(string contact)
    {
        return InfoRepository.GetInfoByContact(contact);
    }
```

my InfoRepository class looks like this

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;

   namespace Test_Net_Test_Info.Models
   {
      public class InfoRepository
      {
       public static List<Info> GetAllInfoss()
      {
        Test_NETEntities dataContext = new Test_NETEntities();
        var query = from info in dataContext.Infoss select info;
        return query.ToList();
      }
      public static Info GetInfoById(int id)
      {
        test_NETEntities dataContext = new test_NETEntities();
        v*emphasized text*ar query = (from info in dataContext.Infos where info.ID ==id   select info).SingleOrDefault();
        return query;
      }
    public static Info GetInfoByContact(string contact)
    {
        Test_NETEntities dataContext = new Test_NETEntities();
    //    var query = (from info in dataContext.Infos where info.Contact == contact  select info).SingleOrDefault();
    //    return query;
    //}
    public static Info GetInfoByCompany(string company)
    {
        Test_NETEntities dataContext = new test_NETEntities();
        var query = (from info in dataContext.Infos where info.Company == company select info).SingleOrDefault();
        return query;
    }
```

I am getting an error Test_Net_Test_Info.Controllers. already defines a member called 'Get' with the same parameter types. I am trying to retrieve data by Company name and Contact name. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method signatures are ambiguous. Changing the name will fix the issue:

```
public Info GetByCompany(string company)
{
    return InfoRepository.GetInfoByCompany(company);
}

public Info GetByContact(string contact)
{
    return InfoRepository.GetInfoByContact(contact);
}
```

In both your method calls, the only thing the compiler sees is this (the signature):

```
Info GetByContact(string)
```

It doesn't know how to choose between the `company` and `contact` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for reply.where to make these changes in the repository class or in the controller class.

Comment: In the controller class, that one is accessed by the external code.

Comment: I did that now it built successfully but how can I test those method on browser.

Comment: I made changes in webapiconfig.cs as below to resove the above error like this config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } now not hetting any error but when I type URL on browser getting an localhost:49579/api/Infos/GetInfoByContact/'xyx'; >

Comment: localhost:49579/api/Infos/GetInfoByContact/'xyx'; <Error> <Message> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'localhost:49579/api/Infos.GetAttorneyByContact/xyz. </Message> <MessageDetail> No type was found that matches the controller named 'Infos.GetInfoByContact'. </MessageDetail> </Erro –

Comment: I think your url should be `localhost:49579/api/Infos/GetByContact/xy`.

Comment: I tried localhost:49579/api/Infos/GetByContact?contact=xyz and it worked. Thanks a lot for all your help and time

Answer (score 1):

This is one area where HTTP verbs and C# method signatures don't always get along.  One approach could be to combine them into a single method:

```
public Info Get(string company = null, string contact = null)
{
    if (company != null)
        return InfoRepository.GetInfoByCompany(company);
    if (contact != null)
        return InfoRepository.GetInfoByContact(contact);
    // throw an exception?  some other default action?
}
```

Then you'd just be relying on the model binder to populate the method arguments based on the request.

(You might also use checks on `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` instead of `null`.)

Comment: Thanks for reply but what if both are not null or if I want call Get method on search button click event at front end.

Comment: @user2897967: If both are not null then default to some action.  (Just put the more common/likely condition first, basically.)  The advertised/documented API wouldn't allow that, so the behavior from the client's perspective is undefined anyway.  As for invoking this from front-end code, that hasn't changed in any way.  However you're making GET requests to the API *now* would still work.

Comment: I have more search methods like based on City, State so want to have separate call or button for each search criteria. By using above logic user has to put null or space while passing the parameter?

Comment: @user2897967: The parameters are optional, the user doesn't have to include them at all.  `/api/Infos/?company=some_company` and `/api/Infos/?contact=some_contact` will both invoke this method.  You can create much more complex searches by using `POST` instead of `GET` and including a more structured object of search parameters.  But if you just want to supply a single parameter on the query string then this will do fine.

Comment: Thank you for help but can you give me simple example of controller as well as repository method how to define that. And test it on browser you can suggest changes in above classes as well . I will try that I would highly appreciate that. In above method which you have posted there are 2 parameters so how it is going to distinguish between company and contact if we pass one parameter. to invoke Get method at front end. do we need to make changes in webapiconfig .cs file.

Comment: @user2897967: The answer I gave *is* an example of a controller method.  I'm not suggesting any changes to your repository class or any changes to your API.  And the model binder will distinguish the parameters based on the *names* of the parameters.  (See the sample URLs in my previous comment.)  You don't need to change your routes or any configurations.  (Unless you've *already* changed them to something custom which would prevent this from working, that is.)  Why is this such a problem?  Did you *try* this?  Is there some specific way in which it's not working?

Comment: @user2897967: What happens when a user includes more than one parameter is a matter of business logic, not of the implementation structure. *Should* they see only one result set? Then only return one result set. (Which is what my code currently does.) *Should* they see two result sets concatenated? Then combine the results of both repository methods and return that? *Should* that combined result be filtered for unique results? Then filter it and return the filtered set. This has nothing to do with the original error.

Comment: @user2897967: Right, the last comment needs to be replaced with some kind of action.  Did you *read* the comment?  Either return a value or throw an exception, since in C# all code paths need to produce a result of some kind in a non-void function.  Also, please stop repeatedly spamming me with a copy/paste of the exact code from my answer.